# Как получить координаты именованного диапазона

Tags: google-apps-script

Как в скрипте правильно обращаться **по имени** столбца с назначенным именованным диапазоном, например,

- как прочитать данные строки №3 столбца "price" ?
- или как в цикле сделать выборку всех данных из именованных столбцов "name", "birthday"?

Пример:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(values[i]['name']+' '+values[i]['birthday']); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить объект Range по его имени вы можете с помощью [getRangeByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeByName(String))

Получить все именованные диапазоны можно с помощью метода [getNamedRanges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getNamedRanges())

Answer (score 0):

Для начала необходимо [плучить сам именованный диапазон](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeByName(String)), а далее определить номер его колонки или прочие параметры, необходимые для позиционирования.

Получить значение по строке

```
function run1() {
  var sprd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sprd.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var row = 3 - 1;
  var priceCol = sprd.getRangeByName("price").getColumn() - 1;

  var res = "";
  res = Utilities
    .formatString("Цена [строка %s]: %s\n",
      row + 1,
      values[row][priceCol]);

  Logger.log(res);
}
```

Пример перебора диапазона

```
function run2() {
  var sprd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sprd.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var nameCol = sprd.getRangeByName("name").getColumn() - 1;
  var birthCol = sprd.getRangeByName("birthday").getColumn() - 1;

  var res = "";
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    res += Utilities
      .formatString("%s %s\n",
        values[i][nameCol],
        values[i][birthCol]);
  }

  Logger.log(res);
}
```

Пример [Как получить координаты именованного диапазона (836059) #SO](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Rz6qwLSfnrhplxT23GfeFkNFJBhEJ5G6MpHmfHStlE/edit?usp=sharing) (скрипт как bound-проект)

Comment: я решение универсальнее (с выборкой всех диапазонов) чутка раньше чем задал вопрос нашел:

  var nr = sheet.getNamedRanges();  
  var x=[]; for(var i in nr){ x[nr[i].getName()]=nr[i].getRange().getColumn(); }

ну и далее мы можем работать с именами x['name'], x['birthday']

Но считал это костыль и говнокод, было мнение что на Apps Script можно это реализовать и красивее.

Comment: Нормальный подход. Если нужны все диапазоны, то попробуйте поличить их через Sheets API. Там передается подобный вашему `x['name'], x['birthday']` объект. У меня был знакомый, так он все время говорил "говнокод", так соседсткая канализационная труба прям над его рабочим столом прорвалась. Совпадение?